# Can smartphones, like iPhone 12 Pro, replace entry-level DSLR cameras?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr, iphone, apple

I am new to this photography. I was planning on buying an entry-level DSLR like Canon Rebel SL3 with a few lenses (18-55 mm, 70-300 mm, and 50 mm prime lens), but after the [iPhone 12 pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_12_Pro) release I started wondering if this DSLR is any good compared to the phone? Can I just buy the new iPhone instead?

Comment: if this was [for the iPhone 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qMkvhCX2pk), imagine with the new lens system  - as a Professional, the DSLR will provide you with all you want as gives full manual control, while the mobile will be semi-auto... you can change things, but it will always have to "say" something about it, meaning, it will always try to override some of your inputs for a "better" image.

Comment: @balexandre Your comment would work great as an answer. [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Comment: A DSLR can zoom in hardware.  No phone can simulate what a 300 mm can do.

Comment: This is like asking if a new model pickup truck can replace an entry level bulldozer? It all depends upon the job one wants to do with it.

Comment: Here is a relevant discussion https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108530/can-an-old-dslr-be-upgraded-to-match-modern-smartphone-image-quality

Answer (score 34):

*There is no clear answer: That depends on your type of photography.*

If you want the camera just to take the usual this and that photos, you are probably not missing out very much. The computational support in the phone has come quite a way and is improving with astonishing speed.

You will notice some limitations: Due to the small sensor, the performance in low light is limited. The phone's image enhancement will do its best, and is now (year 2022) able to negate a lot of the effects by computational de-noising.

**Things you can do with the phone, you probably cannot do that easily with the entry level dslr**

- Filming without knowing what you do, including slow motion
- Carry it around you ALL the time
- Photos in very wet environments
- Automated panorama

**Things that are hard or impossible with a phone**

- low light photography (depends of post processing capabilities)
- anything that needs long time exposures or filters for artistic effect (like ND filters for landscape)
- Anything that needs a flash (you will have to use continuous light for any elaborate lighting, but then you cannot easily freeze action with continuous light)
- Zoom lenses. The best phones have a 5x optical zoom lens, equivalent to ~130mm. With a DSLR you can get a 400mm-equivalent lens cheaply (250mm lens on a crop sensor).

I am assuming that you use a third party photo app on the phone to have basic access to the settings a photo is taken with.

*Note: After seeing a comparison video by Tony Northrup, I have changed some thoughts about low light photography.*

Comment: Novices don't even imagine the concept of NOT using full auto mode for better control.

Comment: There's also something to be said for the more direct control a DSLR gives.  It's really nice to be able to zoom by twisting the ring instead of having to fiddle with a slider or pinching the phone screen.

Comment: Also, there is a significant difference in your mental focus when you're looking through your camera instead of at it.  The DSLR eyepiece blocking out everything but your frame can be a huge help to your concentration.

Comment: Does "sensor" also include the lens (light gathering capability)?

Comment: `Photos in very wet environments`  Well, this is specific to the iPhone 12 and a few other highly waterproof phones.  DSLRs are pretty tough, and can put up with pretty challenging environments - moreso, I'd say, than most phones, generally.

Comment: @J... OP asks about entry level DSLRs...I've taken my XXD and XD Canon's into some pretty wet/dusty/just-overall-crap environments...but I'm not sure the entry level bodies or lenses would have survived (or survived to keep on working as designed for awhile)

Comment: @J...The op specifically mentioned the iPhone 12 - and while semi-pro and pro dslrs are usually astonishingly water resistant, he compares that to entry level ones, which are seldom very water resistant. And even if the cam is, the basic lenses lack any of that.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 If you add your comments as an answer, I'll upvote; I think this is an important part of the overall experience (and result as well). Relatedly, I'd say it's much easier to hold an actual camera still (especially so if you prop it against your face when looking through the eyepiece). When snapping a photo with a smartphone, I find I need to take on average 3 shots to get something without obvious motion blur due to camera shake (phone shake).

Comment: @Kahovius there are a couple of factors that make this worse. One is also common on compact cameras without viewfinders - holding the device away from your face increases shake because it's on a longer lever and not touching your head. The other is that often shooting and almost always other controls are done by poking the screen, which at best encourages holding the phone badly, and at worst actively moves the camera as you shoot.  For static subjects a half-second delay would be helpful; for moving subjects the inherent delay (e.g. it decides to refocus) can be bad enough

Comment: Knowing your automatic modes and how to bend them is very handy when you are short on time or other resources.

Comment: You forgot "being able to instantly post to social media" ;)

Comment: With a proper case one can go diving with DSLR. And the iPhone will die.

Comment: @Crowley I have no knowledge about diving with DSLRs, but pressure-wise I have a hard time believing that a DSLR in a case would go a lot further than an iPhone in a case. To be fair though, googling around the first deep diving case for iphones went 50 meters whilst the two I found for DSLRs went 61 en 100 meters.

Comment: To be fair high end smartcameras by this point take acceptable (still worse than DSLR) low light photos. I sincerely believe putting that in the 'impossible to hard' list is pushing it.

Comment: @DavidMulder For what purpose? I think the smathcams are still useless for large print quality because of A.I. corrections.

Comment: @Crowley the purpose would be to take photos, in the same way that that's always the purpose. I have no idea where you took the large print quality requirement from. The point is that you can go diving with both, although their is a huge difference in cost.

Comment: @DavidMulder because in large prints one can see the details the algorithms in smartphones extrapolate. If you target for 5" displays this is useless - the exptrapolated details are in order of 2 pixels... Even the 4K displays are silly compared to photography sensors regarding resolution.

Comment: I have to disagree with "hard or impossible on phone" for low light photography. It is actually much much easier with a modern phone to do that and the results will be very much decent in the eyes of many. Sure, if your goal is to print the result, it will not be adequate, but if the main purpose is to share it on phones, it is very much sufficient. With a DSLR, you need a good lens, a tripod, and experience. The algorithms in phones make incredible shots possible, it's not just about the lens and sensor

Comment: @Crowley Your comment was that "with a proper case one can go diving with DSLR", then I pointed out that there was no difference, and you mentioned that that has no purpose as large prints would not be good enough... why would deep diving come with a large print requirement? And even beyond that not sure the claim is true, but don't really care anyway (big prints that are viewed from close up are super rare)

Comment: @DavidMulder The comment was agianst so-called waterproof phones (with many of them having tiny-letter claims that insurance does not cover long immersion in fluids including water) being able to underwater (without special diving cases). DSLRs are, in my opinion, for large prints, large displays or art photography. For moments, "see mom, I was there with Bob" the phones are perfect. If I would go diving, I would take phone in case (DSLR would be in this case like hunting rabbits with Katusha rocket launchers). If I would go diving to shoot fish down there, I would use DSLR.

Answer (score 17):

(I'm promoting my comments to an answer now that I have a little more time.)

In addition to all the points brought up in other answers, there are several non-technical, "user experience", reasons that a DSLR is superior to a smart phone.

The first relates to the "immediacy" of the controls.  After a few (dozen) hours using a camera the controls become second-nature in a way that a phone never will.  The two most used functions of a camera are the shutter button and the zoom.  When you hold a DSLR these both are right where your hands naturally fall.  It is much easier, faster, and more precise to change focal length by twisting the ring that's already in your left hand than it is to move a slider or pinch your fingers on the screen of a phone.  Similarly, pushing a shutter button on a larger camera body is a lot less effort than pushing a tiny button on your phone that was designed for occasional use with your thumb.

The second is that there is a significant difference between looking *through* your camera and looking *at* your camera.  When your eye is to the viewfinder of a DSLR the rest of the world is blocked out and all you can see is your frame.  This allows a much deeper focus on what exactly is in the frame you're about to capture.  This may seem like a minor thing, but I think it actually makes a huge difference in how your end results look and how quickly you improve if you're taking the craft of photography seriously.

Comment: Actually, you can shoot both-eyes-open which, after some training, is very useful. One eye is completely blocked by the cam while the other is almost free. And the humongous advantage of the viewfinder is in the sunlight - while the screen can be hard to read, VF is perfectly visible.

Comment: I definitely agree on the ease of control.  I have a DSLR with a normal zoom setup and I have a bridge camera that I often carry hiking when I have no specific photographic objectives--it's got 25-600 effective but the zoom is not done with a ring--I find it much harder to use, I've lost a lot of shots at the far end of the zoom because it's so hard to hold the composition while zooming in close enough.

Answer (score 10):

On top of what has been said, part of a photographer's skills is to make arbitrages between light received, exposure time, and depth of field.

With a smartphone, you may experiment with framing, which is very important, but you won't really be able to experiment with light, exposure and depth of field.

In a sense, it is like learning to play guitar with only 3 strings. You may make music but you will remain limited in your expression and subjects.

Comment: Rather than a "guitar with 3 strings", it's more like a synthesizer with auto-accompaniment and keys highlight...

Comment: You could say that, but some "keys" are indeed missing : you can not control aperture and you don't have enough light coming in :  you will not be able to control depth of field, you won't be able to render low-light moving objects.

Comment: Yes, and if you are into Portraits with constant light, it might work. I am following an Instagram account that does exactly that. I like what I see there. So, if it fits the niche, why not.

Comment: @Zeus Did you mean comparing Guitar hero (TM) to a Fender Stratocaster(TM) with old Marshall(TM) amp?

Comment: This answer could be improved by highlighting the strength of high end smartphones in comparison to low end dslrs. The counter of the point you raise for example is that it takes most amateur photographers more time to take a photo with a DSLR and that they might have to think about technical issues rather than the subject, thus limiting their expression and photos. Doesn't make your point less valid (it's true, lots of shots can't be taken with smartphones), but it's not a one way win. (Also worth noting that some cameras do allow a fair bit of technical control)

Comment: @DavidMulder I tend to think that the only real strength of the smartphone is that it is always available to you anywhere, so you can't miss a memory. I would seriously challenge that it is a recommended path to learn photography, as, as you said, most DSLRs have an automatic mode.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of things have been touched on but upon re-reading your question and seeing you'd get multiple lenses 18-55 mm, 70-300 mm, and 50 mm prime. There is no way a camera phone is going to function with as much versatility as the package you're proposing.  Digital zoom is not a feature.  It's just cropping a photo.  You won't touch a 300mm lens with a camera phone.  What the camera phone is for, in my opinion: Its there, convenient and in your pocket.  Again, it does kinda depend on what you want a camera for.  You have a lot of lenses there that would have different use cases. Just an example, if you were going to use the 300mm lens for wildlife photos then obviously you're not going to get that with a phone.  If you're going to use the 50mm prime that has a super low f stop to make nice portraits, the phone might get closer but still is not going to have the same aesthetic. If you're genuinely interested in photography as a hobby or art, then get a dslr. if you just want to snap photos of stuff stick with the phone and save some money. I imagine though too that you already have some type of camera phone. I don't expect the iphone 12 to be THAT much different from what you have now.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

The smartphones are small, easy to use, allways connected to networks, stuffed with all the filters... They, actually, replaced them years ago. But through point-and-shoot cameras.

**No.**

The smartphone geometry will never allow to build such optics that can barely close to the DSLR/Mirrorless. Each pixel needs some area to gather photons, the more area it has the more photons it can gather at a time and thus one needs lower amplification to get same intensity value for the pixel. Also, if the pixel is too small it can't detect light anymore and quantum physics starts working against your needs.

You know that the smartphone sensor it is 4.5 mm milimeters wide (17.3 mm2). On the other hand, the fullframe sensor is 36 mm wide (864 mm2). Medium size (Kodak, Hasselblad) is 80mm square (6400 mm2).

Another problem is "the glass". Smartphone lenses are around 10 mm wide and thin stack, one can barely change the optical properties of the stack. That's why the ancient (smart)phones had one camera and the new photophones are having many cameras (the more camera, the more adidas). On the other hand DSLR lenses are 50 mm and more wide and significantly longer. Bigger things are easier to build with simillar or better accuracy and one can get wider range of setups.

In other words, for instant photography, the smartphones already replaced them. For prints and photography under not-ideal conditions the DSLR can be beaten only by mirrorless cameras. But in speed, it's hard to beat them.

So, if you are to be instagrammer, DSLR is not for you. If you want to think about things like apperture, shutter speed, flash units, depth-of-focus, then decent DSLR is for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is, of course, an XKCD for this: https://xkcd.com/1235/

Basically, what everybody else has said with particular emphasis on not relying on "megapixelage" as the sole metric of how good a camera is. Broadly speaking, you'll get a better photo with an old DSLR (let's say 3 megapixels) with a true zoom lens which allows you to frame your subject properly than with a new 'phone which only supports "digital" zoom. And a camera with a true zoom (or a fixed-focus telephoto) is far kinder when photographing people since you don't get forced perspective making their nose stand out like a toucan's.

Thanks to @JS for pointing out that these days a 3 megapixel camera is so far down the relative quality curve that it's probably best avoided. 8-12Mpx cameras are readily available second hand, and even if recently manufactured 'phones are up around the 50Mpx mark a DSLR with a lesser sensor but better lenses will give one a run for its money.

Comment: [There's an xkcd for pretty much everything](https://xkcd.com/1014/)

Comment: A minor nit: OP, please do not buy any camera that only has 3 Mpix resolution.  Your future self will curse you if you do.  Source: Lots of 3 Mpix photos in my photo "books".  I couldn't do better at the time.  Today's photographers have no excuse.

Comment: @JS very true, but I was using it as for the purpose of comparison with a smartphone, and I did specifically say "old"... perhaps I could have usefully emphasised that.

Answer (score 2):

A phone will be nowhere near as good as a camera if:

- You want long-range (planes,  birds, wild-life, etc)
- You want a bit more creative control (motion blur, shallow dof, etc)
- You will edit the photos later on photoshop/lightroom/gimp/etc. I don't mean remove/add things, even for basic fixes like white balance, saturation, etc. Saving RAW, never jpeg.

My phone (galaxy note) is more expensive than all my gear combined (T6, EFS 24, 55-250, 60 macro), but there is no comparison once do one of those things. Once you start pixel peeping and trying new crops and etc, the phone just falls short by miles. I tried to used my phone as a B roll camera for when I'm using a long lens (like a 600mm rental for airshows) but it's disgustingly bad.

Btw, don't buy the Canon EF 75-300mm. I had one but following advice from here I traded it for the 55-250 STM and it is mindboggling better. I wouldn't give the 18-55 DC or the 75-300 DC to my worst enemy. Slow to focus, not sharp at all, not stabilized, just a waste of glass.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple good answers, but I'm going to approach it from a different direction:

On an easy shot a modern phone is within the ballpark of a DSLR.  While there still is a difference it rarely matters.

What does matter is when the shot isn't so easy for whatever reason.  Multiple answers have already touched on zoom--only optical zoom matters, digital "zoom" should be nuked from orbit, it's just cropping the shot, not zooming anything.

I can handhold a DSLR with reasonable success a couple of stops below what I can do with a phone and good vibration reduction can add another three stops or so--I have shot plenty of well-lit interior shots without running up the ISO (and thus the noise level.)  I even have some lucky ones that weren't well lit but came out good anyway.

You have no reasonable equivalent of a tourist remover filter on a phone.  On a DSLR you can put your camera on a tripod, compose, focus, carefully put a 10-stop filter on the camera and take your shot.  Basically anything mobile and not too dense in your scene vanishes--you get a shot of nobody around while people were walking back and forth the whole time.  (Somebody sitting in the scene is another matter, though.)

You also have no equivalent of a polarizing filter.  They can sometimes dramatically change the sky in landscape shots.

Note that high-ISO performance has gotten good enough that low light isn't as much of a stumbling block as it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

In recent years, I have seen smartphone photos taken by others that totally blew away any reservation I previously had about using smartphones for photography or video.

The usual assertion has been that phone cameras :

1. Lack ability to change the focal length. But when you look at what they have done, its really not much different from using a prime lens on a Digital Camera, where the focal length is fixed. So this is really not such a big deal. And moreso now you have phones with multiple lenses with different fixed focal lengths, blurring the distinction between a fixed focal length lens and zooms.
2. Have small sensors, and do not let in much light. Sure its impossible to violate pure physics, but when you look at the improvements in sensors, and the increase in the size of sensors of more recent phones, that combination of improvements has narrowed the advantage that digital cameras have.
3. Obviously, todays phone cameras lack fully interchangeable lenses, and that's not in dispute, but really its always going to be a trade off, and this is not about just phone vs dedicated digital cameras. Every camera of any kind makes compromises in one way or another, including size or cost, and cannot be all things to all people, so lets think of it like choosing a car, we now have a choice - electric, hybrid, diesel, petrol - you choose, and all these engines can take you to the same destination however in different ways. Like food there are different kinds, home cooked, takeaway, fast food, 4 course meal in an Italian or French haute cuisine restaurant, and you choose what you want to eat at each point in time, based on your needs/constraints.

For most people, I can see a transition, where for most purposes they just use their phone camera to capture the moment, typically using auto mode... To capture the kind of photos which they might miss, cos unless you are an ardent professional, none carries a traditional digital camera everywhere with them.

And the traditional digital camera is clearly reserved for those events where there has been forethought enough to accommodate the lugging of a larger camera to the event.

Ultimately is really not about the camera type, but the end users preferences. And that is a matter of personal opinion. Who determines if photos taken by one camera or another are good enough? I think there is value in the focus of activity that a dedicated camera provides, similar to going to a cinema to watch a film and devote that time, undividedly to it, when you could obviously have streamed the same video over the internet and paid for this service.

Beyond the "quality" of the end results, which could be subjectively indistinguishable for many kind of photo styles, it comes down to personal preference, and which approach makes you take better photos, that you like.

Like different media in painting (oil, watercolor, acrylic, charcoal, etc) each camera has its own aesthetic that is imprinted on the photo, by design, and this is not a function of the format (dedicated vs integrated phone camera), and this also varies from one phone to another, each new model looking that bit more "clean", and same goes for digital dedicated cameras, each has their own "look".

What I would suggest is like food, try each one out, borrow one of each and experiment. The proof is in the eating, you'll know which one you prefer, or like me, appreciate each for their advantage and have both. It does not need to be a choice between one and the other, you can have both. Phone camera and DSLR/Mirrorless.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:  Get the iPhone 12.  If you are carrying a DSLR you're gonna have a phone with you anyway. If it's a great phone, then why carry a DSLR? If you are really enjoying photography after a year, then go buy a used DSLR and get new lenses as your interests grow.  If you don't like it then sell it. If you want better, then sell it and buy better.
Reasoning:
Over the past two years I've won $500 in photo contest prize money with a Pentax K5, and $800 with the iPhone 6. Those are 12 year old and 8 year old products. The prizes were won primarily due to recognizing the photo opportunity, and secondarily having equipment that was just good enough.
The strength of the iPhone 6 is that it's always with me.  I can take it into difficult environments  where I wouldn't take the DSLR. In a ziplock bag when wading in deep water which I do a lot for work. So it's always ready for a spur of the moment image when the light and subject are right.  Using the DSLR must be planned in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of photography you want to shoot. I personally couldn’t see doing “street” photo without a camera that has immediate access to physical controls.

That said, personally I think the iPhone takes incredible photos for me and love using it for portraits/landscape type shots (I have the iPhone 12 Pro Max)

I’m attaching some shots with the most recent iPhone. Even the improvements in low light have impressed me (though a bit cumbersome to use “Nightmode”.

[image: photo 1] [image: photo 2][image: photo 3][image: photo 4][image: photo5][image: photo 6][image: photo 7]

Answer (score 0):

While it has been mentioned, I don’t believe it has been emphasized sufficiently. I am a serious amateur with a lot of DSLR equipment. I schlepped it all all over Asia and Europe, and got some amazing photographs. But now I have a iPhone 12 pro max and I will never go back. I am just too old to be carrying all that camera equipment with me every day on a long adventure. Taking it on the plane and through costumes and into and out of hotels and cars and vans and always making sure you have everything and that it is all secured carefully is a real hassle. I will not dispute some of the artistic and creative advantages of a DSLR but please do not overlook the convenience factor. The difference between simply putting an iPhone in your back pocket and logging around all of your camera equipment for many hours in a new environment cannot be overstated. And for me, the photo quality is not only sufficient it is outstanding. I mainly post my photos to social media and share them with friends. I made slide shows and similar presentations occasionally and I will print a special shot and give it to a friend at times. Just please do not overwork the convenience and portability of the iPhone when making your decision.Plus, it takes damn good shots.

Comment: until you start pixel peeping...  I don't disagree with the "carry around" argument tho. I'd argue for something like a canon RP with a pancake lens (or the r8), a6000 series, GH series from Pana... All very decent cameras, paired with a sensible small prime.